# Docker image of Azure Storage Emulator - nginx error

Tags: azure, docker, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I am trying to run a docker image of Azure Storage Emulator, latest version available on docker hub. It starts for a few seconds, creates container but immediately I am getting this error:

`nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of parameter, expecting ";" in command line`

[image]

Is this an issue with the image or my environment? What am I looking at, I'm not sure what to debug.

Comment: are you running Windows containers or Linux containers on Windows? I guess the storage emulator container is only for Linux

Comment: @CharlesXu I will check your solution after work, will let you know and accept the answer :)

Comment: the docker image for tablestorage emulator does only support Windows containers FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my test, the same error came out and then I change something below and it works well.

Append one line in the file `nginx.conf`:

```
daemon off;
```

Change the last two lines in the Dockerfile into this:

```
ENTRYPOINT C:\entrypoint.cmd
CMD nginx.exe
```

You can get all the things in the Github [here](https://github.com/tg123/Docker-AzureStorageEmulator). Hope it helps. If any more questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Any chance you could explain why it didn't work in the first place, what exactly was the issue with that last line in Dockerfile?

Comment: @Varin Generally, the Dockerfile is no big problem. But actually, we set the configuration of Nginx in the nginx.conf, and the ENTRYPOINT and the CMD in the same format. It's a good habit.